# Implement Interface in Adapter class in android

Tags: android, web-services, interface, implementation

I am trying to call a webservice from adapter class which extends `BaseAdapter`. I want to implement interface class in this adapter class. But when i run the application, it throws me `ClassCastException`. :-

> **java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mahi.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.mahi.interfaces.AsyncInterface**

Here is my code :-

```
public class NewLibsAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements AsyncInterface {

    public NewLibsAdapter(Context context, Fragment fragment, int positionNo) {

        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.positionNo = positionNo;

        userId = AppMethod.getIntegerPreference(context, AppConstant.ID);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(AppConstant.NAMESPACE, AppConstant.METHOD_NAME_GET_USER_LIBRARY);

        request.addProperty("uid", userId);
        request.addProperty("reccount", recCount);

        DotNetWS logInWS = new DotNetWS(context, request, AppConstant.METHOD_NAME_GET_USER_LIBRARY, AppConstant.GetUserLibraryWS);
        logInWS.execute();

    }

    // This is my interface override method
    @Override
    public void onWSResponse(String json, String WSType) {
        Log.e(TAG, json);
    }

}
```

Here is my DotNetWS class :-

```
public class DotNetWS extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    Context context;
    SoapObject request;
    AsyncInterface asyncInterface;
    String action;
    String wsType;

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    public DotNetWS(Context context, SoapObject request, String action, String wsType) {
        this.context = context;
        this.request = request;
        this.action = action;
        this.wsType = wsType;
        this.asyncInterface = (AsyncInterface) context;
    }

    public DotNetWS(Context context, Fragment fragment, SoapObject request, String action, String wsType) {
        this.context = context;
        this.request = request;
        this.action = action;
        this.wsType = wsType;
        this.asyncInterface = (AsyncInterface) fragment;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setTitle("Connecting...");
        pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // Coding
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        asyncInterface.onWSResponse(s, wsType);
    }

}
```

Is there any solution for this kind of error. Can i implement interface class in adapter class? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can u post the complete logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, inside adapter:

```
 DotNetWS logInWS = new DotNetWS(this, request,                   
 AppConstant.METHOD_NAME_GET_USER_LIBRARY, AppConstant.GetUserLibraryWS);
    logInWS.execute();
```

You are sending your **context** like parameter, but your context is MainActivity, you have to **send** your **adapter class** (this, or NewLibsAdapter.this).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `DotNetWS`constructors And you are calling the `DotNetWS`constructor

```
DotNetWS logInWS = new DotNetWS(context, request, AppConstant.METHOD_NAME_GET_USER_LIBRARY, AppConstant.GetUserLibraryWS);
```

which casts context as `AsyncInterface`. Are you sure?

```
this.asyncInterface = (AsyncInterface) context;
```

According to error text, this context do not implements `AsyncInterface`.